# QOpenGLWidget video rendering perfomance in multiple processes

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ffmpeg

My problem may seem vague without code, but it actually isn't.

So, there I've got an *almost* properly-working widget, which renders video frames.

Qt 5.10 and QOpenGLWidget subclassing worked fine, I didn't make any sophisticated optimizations -- there are two textures and a couple of shaders, converting YUV pixel format to RGB -- `glTexImage2D()` + shaders, no buffers.

Video frames are obtained from FFMPEG, it shows great performance due to hardware acceleration... when there is only one video window.

The piece of software is a "video wall" -- multiple independent video windows on the same screen. Of course, multi-threading would be the preferred solution, but legacy holds for now, I can't change it.

So, 1 window with Full HD video consumes ~2% CPU & 8-10% GPU regardless of the size of the window. But 7-10 similar windows, launched from the same executable at the same time consume almost *all the CPU*. My math says that 2 x 8 != 100...

My best guesses are:

- This is a ffmpeg decoder issue, hardware acceleration still is not magic, some hardware pipeline stalls
- 7-8-9 independent OpenGL contexts cost a lot more than 1 cost x N
- I'm not using PUBO or some other complex techniques to improve OpenGL rendering. It still explains nothing, but at least it is a guess

The behavior is the same on Ubuntu, where decoding uses different codec (I mean that using GPU accelerated or CPU accelerated codecs makes no difference!), so, it makes more probable that I'm missing something about OpenGL... or not, because launching 6-7 Qt examples with dynamic textures shows normal growth of CPU usages -- it is approximately a sum for the number of windows.

Anyway, it becomes quite tricky for me to profile the case, so I hope someone could have been solving the similar problem before and could share his experience with me. I'd be appreciated for any ideas, how to deal with the described riddle.

I can add any pieces of code if that helps.

Comment: If the issue is with CPU then you should profile your code. If you use old fixed-pipeline OpenGL then perhaps, only perhaps, you have an issue with RAM-to-GPU data movement. These are only guesses. Without profiling and seeing your code nothing can be asserted.

Comment: Qt's problem? Unsure. I don't want to mislead you but: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opengl-performance-tips-swap-frame-buffer-objects-fbo-instead-of-surfaces-using-a-single How is that applicable to your problem exactly, I wish I could express it in the actual answer.

Comment: I roughly remember that OpenGL context switches are expensive. However, I remember also that `QOpenGLWidget`s may share a context. There's a subject in Qt doc. for this: [Context Sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#context-sharing)

Comment: @Ripi2, good guess but no, I'm using shaders/buffers and all other stuff from the new pipeline.It has to be profiling, but the tricky thing is somewhat about I described: _one_ "demo.exe" works fine, _eight_ exe's simultaneously work lame. And they share no data at all =(

Comment: @AlexanderV, yeah, that's about OpenGL optimizations, was thinking to use some of it, but my doubt origins in single-launched-app good perfomance. I'd consder it to be the bottleneck otherwise.

Comment: @Scheff, hmm, thanks! That could be something

Comment: _one "demo.exe" works fine, eight exe's simultaneously work lame._ This might be caused by GL context switches although this is not anymore that expensive than in the past on the SGI Irix workstations where I learnt this. So, video decoding might have similar issues but about that I don't know anything. However, I've no idea how multiple processes may shared a GL context (although this might be possible). In one process this is not that difficult. It should be described in the link I provided in my last comment (if it's not even the default).